# Django with Instagram API. How to fix the encoding error?

Tags: django, python-3.x, instagram-api

Good morning, I'm trying to connect Instagram API with Django. I'm getting Instagram code and give this code to function response().

```
def response(request):
if 'code' in request.GET:
    url = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token'
    values = {
        'client_id':'SOME_ID',
        'client_secret':'SOME_SECRET',
        'redirect_uri':'SOME_URL',
        'code':request.GET.get('code'),
        'grant_type':'authorization_code'
    }
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
    bin_data = data.encode('utf-8')
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=bin_data)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    response_string = response.read()
    insta_data = json.loads(response_string)
    if 'access_token' in insta_data and 'user' in insta_data:
        #authentication success
        print('True')
    else:
        #authentication failure after step 2
        print('False 2')
elif 'error' in request.GET:
    #authentication failure after step 1
    print('False 1')
```

But I'm get TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str. What I'm doing wrong? Why when I encode to 'utf-8' or 'ascii' nothing happens?

Comment: Instagram has a Python API client, you should use that. Or at the very least, use requests rather than urllib.

Comment: Try Instagram python module https://pypi.org/project/instagram-python/